# How do I find and remove duplicate mongo documents with ruby

Tags: ruby, mongodb, duplicates

I have a collection in Mongo with duplicates on a specific key that I need to remove all but one of. The Map Reduce solutions don't seem to make it clear how to remove all but one of the duplicates. I am using Ruby, how can I do this in a somewhat efficient way? My current solution is unbelievably slow!

I currently just iterate over an array of the duplicate keys and delete the first document that is returned but this only works if there are at most 1 duplicate document for each key and it is really slow.

```
dupes.each do |key|
    $mongodb.collection("some_collection").remove($mongodb.collection("some_collection").find({key: key}).first)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use the MongoDB `ensureIndex()` to remove the duplicates. For instance, in your case, you want to drop the duplicate documents give the key `duplicate_key`, you can do

```
db.duplicate_collection.ensureIndex({'duplicate_key' : 1},{unique: true, dropDups: true})
```

where `duplicate_collection` is the collection where your duplicate documents are. This operation will only preserve single document if there are duplicate documents give a particular key.

After the operation, if you think you want to remove the index, just do the `dropIndex` operation. For details, you can search the mongodb documentation.

Comment: That didn't work for me because there were too many documents in my collection that were duplicated and I got the error "too many dups on index build with dropDups=true".

Comment: @Musicalmindz Then, you can just build a new collection based on the old collection. First, you get the list of distinct values for the given key, and then use the `find_one` methods to iterate over the keys and then save the retrieved documents into a collection, and drop the old one :)

Comment: That was definitely an option but we wanted to do the work in place.

Comment: The best answer for me! Works fine! Thks!

Answer (score 0):

A lot of solutions suggest Map Reduce (which is fast and fine) but I implemented a solution in Ruby that seems pretty fast as well and makes it easy to leave the one document from each duplicate set.

Basically you find all your duplicate keys by adding them to a hash and any time you find a duplicate key in the collection you add the id of that document to an array which you will use in a bulk removal at the end.

```
all_keys = {}
dupes = []
    dupe_key = "some_key"

$mongodb.collection("some_collection").find.each do |doc|
   all_keys[doc[dupe_key]].present? ? dupes << doc["_id"] : asins[doc[dupe_key]] = 1
end

$mongodb.collection("some_collection").remove({_id: {"$in" => dupes } })
```

The only issue with this method is that it potentially won't work if the total list of keys/dupe ids can't be stored in memory. The map reduce solution would probably be best at that point.